# How to remove taxonomy term reference field from simplenews newsletter HTML

Tags: emails

I have spent a week watching videos and reading tutorials on how to customize the HTML generated by Simplenews. I'm stuck on how to remove the following from my newsletter. I discovered the following using Firebug. There is a bewildering array of CSS, HTML, and php files that are involved. I'm clueless as to how to find the one that it is control.

Can you tell me how to code CSS in the new theme I created for newsletters to remove the following?

```
div class="field field-name-field-simplenews-term field-type-taxonomy-term-reference field-label-hidden view-mode-full"ul class="field-items"li class="field-item even"a datatype="" property="rdfs:label skos:prefLabel" typeof="skos:Concept" href="/newsletter/test">test</a></li></ul></div
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to

> Home » Administration » Structure » Content types » Simplenews
>   newsletter

Go to Display and customize it

There will be **Newsletter category** - you can change it's format to **Hidden**

But first activate needed display type on that page in

[image: oups it's here]

Full Content fixes the node display. Email HTML fixes it on the email itself.

Comment: That removed it from the email, but it still appears when I click "Click here to view this message on the web." I guess I can live with it showing up there, however.

Comment: I think you should try different display types.

Comment: OK. Got it. Full Content was the one that was being used. I hid it.

Comment: Glad it helped :)